# Beginform com vários button em um form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho form que tem vários buttons, 1 para excluir via aja, 1 para editar via ajax, 1 para abrir relatório e tenho 1 button para quando ele for clicado em desejo fazer o post do formulário, o button do post funciona o problema é que todos os outros também é chamado o método de post.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id ="submitForm" }))
{ 
 <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="command" value="Save">Save</button>
 <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="command" value="Cancel"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você definiu o type deles como submit mude para button, para aqueles que você não quer que façam o submit for formulário e controle seus comportamentos via javascript.

```
<button type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="command" value="Cancel"/>
```